# ASP.net Force Panel below floats

Tags: asp.net

I have two side by side panels floating and another that I want to sit below them:

```
 ----------  -----
|p1        ||p2   |
|          ||     |
|          | -----
|          |
 ----------
-------------------
p3
-------------------
```

However when I create p3 it appears to the right of p2. How can I force it below?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To p3 add:

```
style="clear:left"
```

this will make sure that there is nothing floating to the left of it.

(use `clear:both` for left and right..)